# Strange early end of text found by pyparse

Tags: python-3.x, parsing

Today I had a look at pyparse because I have some assembler files I wanted to compare. For some reason, I started to do so on my Windows Machine with Pyhton 3.8.0 and pyparse 1.1.7. The files I used to parse were downloaded via VSCode (and SSH connection) and stored on a SD Card.

When things finally worked, I put the script onto the Linux Machine running Pyhton 3.6.9 and pyparse 1.1.7 as well. The files were the identical ones.

Yet, I get a weird error (when I run complete_file_layout.runTests(text)) namely: **FAIL: Expected {"Disassembly of section .vector:" | "Disassembly of section .text:"}, found '/'  (at char 0), (line:1, col:1)**

So I guess this has to do with lineendings but I'm not sure how (and couldn't find anything at google or here)

This is my pyparse tryouts, the file starts like this:

```
/home/user/path/to/file/a.out:     file format elf32-somename

Disassembly of section .vector:

80000000 <crtStart>:
```

Now the pyparse part

```
optionales_komma = Optional(Literal(',')).suppress()
func_name = Word(alphas+'_')("func_name")
func_parameters = Optional(Group(Literal('(').suppress() + 
                        OneOrMore( Word(alphas+'*'+'&') + 
                        Optional(',').suppress()) +
                        Literal(')').suppress())).setResultsName('parameters', listAllMatches=True)
func_layout =  func_name + func_parameters
line_layout_func_header = Optional(Word(hexnums) + 
                        Literal('<').suppress() + 
                        func_layout + 
                        Literal('>').suppress() +
                         Literal(':').suppress())

# define layout of an assembler instruction
assembler_layout = OneOrMore(Group(Word(hexnums, min=1, max=3) + 
                Literal(':').suppress() + Word(hexnums, exact=8) + 
                ( Word(hexnums+'0x') | Word(alphas) + 
                (SkipTo(LineEnd(), include=False))))).setResultsName('instructions')

filepath_line = Word(alphanums+'/'+'.'+':'+'_') + Literal('file format') + Word(alphanums+'-') + Suppress(White("\n"))
info_line = Literal('Disassembly of section .vector:') | Literal('Disassembly of section .text:')

complete_file_layout = Optional(filepath_line) + info_line+ OneOrMore(Group(line_layout_func_header + assembler_layout))
```

Any ideas on what I could try? I don't necessarily need the first lines and would skip them (so just get the parts of the file that could actually be matched, but I don't know how to do so either. )

Comment: Are you sure it's actually using Python 3? [The python command starts the the wrong version of the python interpreter](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/403972)

Comment: I explicitly use python3 on the terminal to run the program, so I am 100%sure its Python3. Also, parts of my program use printing-syntax not allowed in python2 but I'm not getting synatx errors (checked by running with python2 - and getting the expected errors message, just in case)

Comment: So I opened the files in notepad++ just to see the ending: its LF.
file name_of_file on my linux shell tells me, its ASCII encoded.
The problem seems to be that pyparse sees the normal Lineendings as End of Text. And I have no clue, why

Comment: On Windows, \r\n is used for the end of a line, and on Linux \n is standard, so maybe the `Suppress(White("\n"))` needs to be `Suppress(White("\r"))` instead. You could check more thoroughly by outputting the ASCII codes of the parsed items on Windows to see if there are spurious \r (ASCII 13) chars in there that aren't otherwise visible.